# Edge crossing each other

Tags: graphviz, dot

is there a way to eliminate the crossing of edges?

I tried many ways, nothing helped.

```
digraph graphname {
    graph [splines=ortho,];
    node [shape=box,];

    l;

    l_a [shape=diamond,label="",height=0.20,width=0.20];
    l_a_s [shape=point];
    l_a_i [shape=point];
    l_a_ii [shape=point];
    l_a -> l_a_s;
    {rank=same; a -> l_a -> l}
    {rank=same; l_a_i -> l_a_s -> l_a_ii}
    l_a_i -> i;
    l_a_ii -> ii;

    l_c [shape=diamond,label="",height=0.20,width=0.20];
    l_c_s [shape=point];
    l_c_t [shape=point];
    l_c_n [shape=point];
    l_c -> l_c_s;
    {rank=same; l -> l_c -> c} 
    {rank=same; l_c_t -> l_c_s -> l_c_n}
    l_c_t -> t;
    l_c_n -> n;
}
```

some more details:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to reorganize your node/edge definitions a little bit, no additional edges needed.

for example:

```
digraph graphname {
    graph [splines=ortho,];
    node [shape=box,];

    a;
    l_a [shape=diamond,label="",height=0.20,width=0.20];
    l;
    l_c [shape=diamond,label="",height=0.20,width=0.20];
    c;
    {rank=same; a -> l_a -> l -> l_c -> c}

    l_a_s [shape=point];
    l_c_s [shape=point];
    l_a -> l_a_s;
    l_c -> l_c_s;

    l_a_i [shape=point];
    l_a_ii [shape=point];
    l_c_t [shape=point];
    l_c_n [shape=point];

    {rank=same;
    l_a_i -> l_a_s -> l_a_ii;
    l_c_t -> l_c_s -> l_c_n;}

    l_a_i -> i;
    l_a_ii -> ii;

    l_c_t -> t;
    l_c_n -> n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this invisible edge solves your problem:

```
    l_a_i -> l_c_s [constraint=false style=invis]
```

I can't prove mathematically why this works, but in such situation it usually helps to play with order in which nodes/edges are defined, or try adding invisible adges to nudge the layout in the direction you need